# Need to find $\mathbb{P}(0<X<2n) \geqslant \frac{n-1}{n}.$

Tags: probability

If $X$ is a $\gamma(n)$ variate then show that  $$\mathbb{P}(0<X<2n) \geqslant \frac{n-1}{n},$$
where, if $F$ is the distribution function of $\gamma(n)$ with positively supported then $$F(x) = \frac 1 {\Gamma(n)} \int_{0}^x e^{-t} t^{n-1}\,dt.$$

Comment: what is a $\gamma(n)$ variate?

Comment: I have added in the question. Thanks @Martin.

Comment: I think what you need is $$ F(x) = \begin{cases} \qquad 0 & \text{if } x<0, \\  \\ \displaystyle \frac 1 {\Gamma(n)} \int_0^x t^{n-1} e^{-t} \, dt & \text{if } x\ge 0. \end{cases} $$

Comment: Oh! yes that's true. Sure. I am sorry. Gamma function is positively supported.

Comment: $\ldots\,$and then what you're looking for is a bound on $F(2n). \qquad$

Comment: Yes. That is what I look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall [Chebychev's Inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevInequality.html):

\begin{align} 
P(|X-E[X] |\geq k\sigma) \leq\frac{1}{k^2}
\end{align} 
Where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $X$. Now choose $k=\sqrt[] {n} $.  Furthermore verify that $E[X] =n$ and $\sigma=\sqrt[]{n}$. Hence:
\begin{align} 
P(|X-n|\geq n) \leq\frac{1}{n}
\end{align} 
By monotonicity one has $$P(X-n\geq n) \leq P(|X-n|\geq n)$$ That means:
$$P(X\geq 2n) \leq\frac{1}{n} $$
But then $$P(X< 2n)=1-P( X\geq 2n) \geq1-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n-1}{n} $$ And that is the desired inequality.

---

**Bonus.** One can do slightly better, because when $n<1$ we have a negative thing on the RHS which its truth is trivial. Verify that we have:
\begin{align}
P(X\geq 2n) \leq \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
by [Markov's Inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MarkovsInequality.html). Hence:
\begin{align}
P(X< 2n) \geq \max\bigg\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{n-1}{n} \bigg\}
\end{align}